# import code html to html5

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to import code another html to div html.
 i have 2 file html.

```html
first.html
<div id="slider1">/import second.html/ </div> 
<div id="slider2">/import second.html/ </div> 
<div id="slider3"> /import second.html/</div>

second.html
<div id="mask">
<ul>
<li class="1"><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/> </a></li>
<li class="2"><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/> </a></li>
<li class="3"><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```

how to import second.html to first.html. i need second.html will show in div slider1 , slider2 and slider3.

Comment: your question is not clear ? do you want to load html page to a div ?

Comment: You may search for php include for server side templating and jquery templating for client side templating.

Comment: this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried **include**?

```
<div id="slider1"><?php include("second.html"); ?></div> 
<div id="slider2"><?php include("second.html"); ?></div> 
<div id="slider3"><?php include("second.html"); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **first.html** file which has 3 sliders.

```js
function(){
  $('.second_file_contents').load('second.html'); // give appropriate path to your file
}
```

```html
//first.html file contents
<div id="slider_1" class="second_file_contents"></div>
<div id="slider_2" class="second_file_contents"></div>
<div id="slider_3" class="second_file_contents"></div>
```

Hope this helps.